# how to run the CWAC-Camera demo?

Tags: android, eclipse, commonsware-cwac

Eclipse will not run the cwac-camera-master demo. The project builds but there is no bin directory and the AndroidManifest.xml has the MainActivity as the category.LAUNCHER.

I have not edited the download per Mark's instructions.  If I uncheck "is Library" then the outter project becomes Runnable but that doesn't have a Launcher.

I'm doing something wrong with the inner/outter project config.  Can someone please point me in a direction?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There are three projects: the Android library project, a `demo/` sub-project, and a `demo-v9/` sub-project.

Download the ZIP archive for the repository and unZIP it somewhere on your development machine. Import the top-level project into Eclipse, then import the `demo/` sub-project into Eclipse. Everything should line up for that. If you wish to import the `demo-v9/` sub-project, you will need to modify that demo project to reference your own copy of ActionBarSherlock, which that demo uses for its action bar.